# How to calibrate the vertical sensitivity of an old analog scope (Hameg HM203-6)?

Tags: oscilloscope, calibration

I have a Hameg HM203-6 20 MHz analog 'scope I bought from a flea shop. There's about 20% mismatch of the readings of the two channels, with CH1's vertical amplification being about 20% higher than CH2 when both are at the "CAL" positions of their respective variable amplification knobs. Using a reliable 5V DC source, I've checked that CH2 shows about 5 volts exactly, whereas CH1 is close to 6 volts. On this model, the "CAL" position is at maximum CCW, and sensitivity cannot be reduced below the calibrated one.

So I assume the "calibrated position" must be recalibrated. The problem is that there's no mention on how to do this in the [manual](http://www.sm5cbw.se/hameg/hmosc/hm203-6-man.pdf) I was able to find. I see those "CH1/CH2 balance" holes on the underside of the case, but they serve a different purpose.

I'm also almost sure that the sensitivity can be calibrated through the VR703 ("Y-GAIN CH1") pot, slightly below the center in [this photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/anachrocomputer/14136099141/in/photostream/).

So my questions are,

1. Is there anything else to it, besides the pot adjustment?
2. Is it a terribly bad idea to do the adjustment while the scope is naked and powered? I'm aware that exposed CRTs are lethally dangerous.

Comment: You should locate the service manual

Comment: The ones I've found are in German, and contain schematics only, no instructions.

Comment: See it as a challange!

Comment: It's probably just as simple as adjusting the pot marked Y-gain.  Should be fine to power it on and adjust it with the cover off, just be careful not to short anything with a metal screwdriver and stay away from the HV supply to the CRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I just tried it and calibrated it myself. The procedure being as follows:

1. Disconnect the power cable, and remove the scope cover;
2. Place the scope vertically, so the VR703 pot can be reached (and the front panel still reachable);
3. Reconnect the power cable, turn the scope on, and supply the reliable 5 volts (in my case it was through a digital Lab PSU, so I also rechecked with 1 volts, 2 volts, etc.), and adjust the pot to get the expected value;
4. Turn off, reassemble, done.

Nothing scary, the scarier part was the amount of spider webbing inside :)